# CheckBox Value to Text in DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a project. How to convert CheckBox tick value to Yes for MySQL database and untick no?

I was able to make simple HTML inputs of Check Boxes. How to set the things above in PHP?

Comment: Can You Please Provide Your **Tried** Code?

Comment: @NanaPartykar it is really simple ... HTML and input tags with CheckBox type

Comment: Frankly Speaking, Question Is Unclear And Broad Too. We Don't Write Code For Seekers. We Try To Help By Observing The Code. If You Really Wanted To Get Out Of The Trouble, Provide Code Which You Tried And Unfortunately Didn't Succeeded To Meet The Requirement. Hope, This Clears @user

Comment: @NanaPartykar Could you please stop writing all words with an uppercase first letter. It's really annoying to read text like that, and that's now how you're supposed to be writing

Comment: @JamesZ: Mind Your Own Business. You Are No One To Ask Me. I Feel Comfortable In This Way. And, I Will Write In This Way Only.

Answer (score 1):

To get the result of the checkbox into a PHP script, submit it as a field in a form either through POST or GET, then in your targeted php script, process the $_POST or $_GET superglobal you chose:

```
if (isset($_POST['Check']) && !empty($_POST['Check'])) {

    $Result = $_POST['Check'];

}
```

To get the result of whether the checkbox is checked or not into the field you can use a single checkbox, and a hidden field in the form to hold the value "Yes" or "no"

```
<fieldset>
    <form action="check.php" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="getSelected(this)" value="Yes">Query
        <input type="hidden" name="Check" id="Status" value="Yes">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

To change the value of the hidden field when the checkbox is checked or unchecked use javascript to set the value of the field:

```
// Set Hidden Field to Result of Checkbox
function getSelected(elem) {

    // Get Hidden Field Reference
    var status = document.getElementById("Status");

    // Determine if Checked
    if(elem.checked) {
        status.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        status.value = "No";
    }

}
```

Then when you submit the form, it is POSTed to the target script and you will have a field "Check" that is either "Yes" or "No". From there you can use PHP to process your variables and then run whatever MySQL queries you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you plz tell me what is to be done by me here. I am really a beginner at php so plz. Thanks